# What is collation at a low level?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

Let's say I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `field` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE `table_2` (
  `field` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_520_ci;
```

The tables are the same except for their field collation. The first table uses (the default) `utf_general_ci` and the second table uses `utf8_unicode_520_c1`.

And I have inserted the value `abcdé` into both tables. I would assume (maybe incorrectly) that both of these characters would be stored with the binary value of: `61` `62` `63` `C3A9`. And both tables return that result when doing:

```
select field, hex(field) from table_1;
# abcé  616263C3A9

select field, hex(field) from table_2;
# abcé  616263C3A9

# Both return the same result
```

Does this mean the value is stored as that binary value or is there more to it as to how a `utf-8` string is stored? Now, when I try doing a `UNION` or `JOIN`, it doesn't allow me to do so due to a mix of collations as it says:

```
select field, hex(field) from table_1 union
select field, hex(field) from table_2;
```

> Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Why does this occur then, and back to my initial question: what is the meaning of collation at the lower/storage level? I thought it was just used for a 'sort' (i.e., not at the storage level, but at the query/algorithmic level).

Comment: How does it change what it looks like at the storage layer? Also, I don't care about the error -- I was just using that as a starting place to answer how collation changes the storage of a string.

Comment: The `C3A9` is the encoding, as indicated by the `CHARACTER SET` of `utf8` or `utf8mb4`.  The `COLLATION` say whether `é` > `e` or `é` < `e` or `é` = `e`.  Or any other character.  It's an algorithm, not an encoding.  In English, the collation says whether or not `A` = `a` (case sensitivity) or not.

Comment: @RickJames I see, and because it affects equality it can affect `join`s and `union`s where the join-values need to be compared for equality. But then why doesn't a `UNION ALL` work? Actually, I'm disappointed this question was closed, because my question isn't really about what the error is but how the collation affects comparisons and queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in the effect of collation on `JOIN` and `UNION`?

First, a review of charset/collation...  The C3A9 is the encoding, as indicated by the CHARACTER SET of utf8 or utf8mb4. The COLLATION say whether é > e or é < e or é = e. Or any other character. It's an algorithm, not an encoding. In English, the collation says whether or not A = a (case sensitivity) or not.

For `JOIN`...

```
FROM a
JOIN b  ON a.x = b.x
```

The Optimizers needs `x` in the two tables to have the same charset and collation.  That way, `INDEX(x)` can be use to efficiently do the `JOIN..ON`.

For `UNION DISTINCT` ...

The column(s) that are involved in `DISTINCTifying` need to be compared.  Comparing is efficient with an index.  Without the same collation, there may be a definitional problem of what to do.

For `UNION ALL` ...

The result is a "table" with columns.  Those columns have datatypes *including collation*.  The simple approach is to demand all the collations be the same.  More complex would be to convert on the fly.

The manual (on `UNION`) says (imprecisely) "For example, the first column selected by the first statement should have the same type as the first column selected by the other statements. If the data types of corresponding SELECT columns do not match, the types and lengths of the columns in the UNION result take into account the values retrieved by all the SELECT statements."

Comment: thanks for this answer and the pointers. Do you have links that you could add that either (1) discuss charset/collation at a more granular level; or (2) in mysql the part you mention above?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the references you desire.  In general mixing collations is problematic.